# jquery insert after multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to insert a span element after a input element matching the  `class` as well as input type that is `checkbox` for styling the checkbox element.

I am able to achieve it for class selector only
for example:
the input element looks like this:

```
<input data-attrname="artist" class="layered_attrs" id="57" type="checkbox">
```

and I want to add the element after this like

```
<span class="checkmark"></span>
```

I can achieve this using:

```
$( "<span class='checkmark'></span>" ).insertAfter( ".layered_attrs" );
```

but I also want to validate type that is input id with class `layered_attrs` and type is `checkbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector:

```
$( "<span class='checkmark'></span>" ).insertAfter( ".layered_attrs:checkbox" );
```

Or [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

```
$( "<span class='checkmark'></span>" ).insertAfter( ".layered_attrs[type='checkbox']" );
```

Comment: just a question, this means you can add any number of selector like that, no need to use comma or space.

Comment: if all the selectors are for that element yes, spaces are for descendants

Comment: Also order not extremely important ... could be `":checkbox.layered_attrs"` also